# "TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime" in Jinja2 template when using strftime

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to format dates generated with `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` (using this because it's the equivalent of `ISODate()` in MongoDB which is the database my app uses) in my Flask application but Jinja2 won't render them.

I have the following function in my app:

```
def format_isodate(timestamp):
    """Format a ISODate time stamp for display."""
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S')
```

The dates look like this:

```
"2013-07-04 20:06:05.088000"
```

And I have the following filter:

```
app.jinja_env.filters['isodateformat'] = format_isodate
```

But when I try to format the timestamp in templates:

```
{{ change.submit_date|isodateformat }}
```

I get this error:

> "TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime"

I don't understand why I am getting this error. Doesn't `strftime()` convert dates to string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `utcnow()` returns a `datetime.datetime` object, not a string. If you check the line number in the exception, it’s likely the `strptime` call that’s failing—it can parse a string into a date, but it can’t parse a date.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import datetime

import jinja2

def format_isodate(timestamp):
    """Format a ISODate time stamp for display."""
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S')

e = jinja2.Environment()
e.filters['isodateformat'] = format_isodate

t = e.from_string('{{ change.submit_date|isodateformat }}')
print t.render(change={'submit_date': "2013-07-04 20:06:05.088000"})
print t.render(change={'submit_date': datetime.datetime.now()})
```

The first print of a string succeeds, but the second one fails with `TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.  
I inserted my date with datetime.datetime.utcnow() which MongoDB via PyMongo understood is a date object (ISODate()) so it saved it as a date object. So when I query the document for the date, I get a date object returned to me as well.  

For the record, I fixed it by replacing the last two rows of my function with this line: `return timestamp.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S")`